# What is best practice when instantiating a web service

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a class library (c#) with many methods that call the same web service (asmx).

What is the best practice for instantiating the web service.

- Instantiate the web service once and pass it as a parameter to each method
- Or instantiate and dispose the web service in each method.

Comment: @Chrystad: Please mark the answer if you have one.

Answer (score 6):

What you are instantiating is a local proxy class that calls the service, so it isn't as costly as you may think.

As web services are supposed to be stateless, either method would work. I doubt you will see much of a difference in performance.

Answer (score 0):

It seams like a bad practice to make a new instance of the service, hook up complete events each time you have to call a service method

usually i make an instance variable 
and then instantiate the service in the constructor and hook up all complete events there

and only call the methods when needed
this approach works well, except if you do it in an User-control it breaks the Visual Studio Designer